# Meaning of dots in Lattice / Galois Connection

Tags: lattice-orders, galois-connections

Wondering what the dots mean (and what the whole element it's a part of means) in the slide below (above `pos` and `neg`). I have seen them in another similar presentation on data-flow lattices and Galois connections.

---

[image]

Comment: The context appears to be https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-820-fundamentals-of-program-analysis-fall-2015/lecture-notes/MIT6_820F15_L18.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is not clear, but maybe pos means greater than zero, and dotted pos means great than or equal to zero? That would be logical, as dotted pos is the unification of pos and 0, for example.